# In a code segment of Hackerrank it was advised to make the string static. Why isn't the code working without static string?

Tags: c, string, static

The following code is giving an error. But when I declare the string static then the same code works.

```
     char* check(int x1, int x2) 
    {
        char str1[]= "YES";
        char str2[]= "NO";
        if((x2-x1)>0) 
            return str1;
        else 
            return str2;  
    }
```

Comment: Youn can try `return x2-x1>0 ? "YES" : "NO";` with the same effect as using `static`

Answer (score 4):

You return pointer to the **automatic** variables - they do not exist when you leave the scope of the function. So it the Undefined Bahaviour and the code "works" by incident only (as usually UB means - **`anything may happen`**)

when you add `static` keyword you change its storage duration to static and they live as long as the program itself.

Most of the modern compilers will emit the warning.
https://godbolt.org/z/_MiuM5

Answer (score 3):

You are returning the address of local automatically allocated arrays. Those cease to exist when the function exits, which makes the returned address no longer valid.

Making the strings `static` keeps them alive all the time, fixing the issue.